# Get original origin of request with .NET Core API

Tags: c#, .net-core

I know that `Request.Headers["Origin"]` gets the origin header of a request, but this is changeable on the client-side by setting the header manually. Thus not that safe.

Is there such a value that contains the original, readonly/unchangeable origin of a request? Like the one CORS is using?

I need this value to check if the request is officially coming from the site it's supposed to come from. The trick is that I need it in the controller method to search an object in the database based on this value and a key only used for that site.

The problem with CORS is that it can whitelist a list of URLs but not check if the site and the key belong to each other, thus can whitelisted site 1 access the data of whitelisted site 2 if it mimics the `Request.Headers["Origin"]` and the key of site 2

Comment: There is no such thing, anyone can call your api with any headers they want. Browser will fill what you call "real" origin, but you have no idea whether request comes from such browser or not

Comment: @Evk How does CORS handle this then? Does this also use the `Request.Headers["Origin"]` value?

Comment: CORS is not a security feature for your server, it's designed to protect _client_ (the browser user). So yes it does use the value of this header, but it is set by browser and _browser_ makes a request to your server and decides how to proceed based on response. You just tell browser which origins are allowed and browser knows the real origin and acts accordingly. You cannot in any way assume that CORS prevents calling your api by anyone

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately (or perhaps fortunately?) there is no reliable way to check this from the data that the browser sends to your server. The user is able to forge any and all information that you receive from the browser.

This is why mechanisms that need to reliably determine the origin of a user use some sort of token mechanism, public/private signatures, certificates and the sort to determine it. Unfortunately this is never as simple as looking up some information that the browser provides you with, so it *seems* like you might need to redesign your whitelisting mechanism by relying on something else than origin, possibly implicating single-sign-on measures (like [SAML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Assertion_Markup_Language)). It's hard to provide further suggestions without more information on the underlying problem that the origin-check is intended to solve.

Comment: I'm kind of a newbie on the front of CORS and the technic behind this and was curious if there was a way of knowing the true origin of a request to secure requests sent to the API. But now that I did a bit of research, I know that I have to use a different way of securing the API and the requests like the SSO-method you mentioned.